# Freeing copies to allocated memory (by getline() function)

Tags: c, getline

I have written the following function to read lines of a text file and save them into a global array:

```c
/* maximum number of lines allowed in one source file */
#define MAXSRCLNS 100
char *G_source_lines[MAXSRCLNS];    /* source lines */
/* number of source lines saved into source_ */
size_t G_source_lines_count = 0;

/*
 * reads the source file 'path' and puts non-empty lines into the
 * array G_source_lines. increments the number of lines
 * G_source_lines_count for each line saved.
 */
void read_lines(char *path)
{
  FILE *stream;
  stream = fopen(path, "r");
  if (!stream) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open source '%s'\n", path);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  char *lnptr = NULL;
  size_t n = 0;
  while ((getline(&lnptr, &n, stream) != -1)) {
    /* throw away empty lines */
    if (!isempty(lnptr)) {
      /* assert(("line count too large", G_source_lines_count < MAXSRCLNS)); */
      G_source_lines[G_source_lines_count++] = lnptr;
    } else {
      /* I don't save an empty line in the G_source_lines for later
     freeing, so free the allocation right here! */
      free(lnptr);
    }
    lnptr = NULL;
  }
  /* free the lnptr variable defined and allocated on this stack */
  /* don't forget to free it's copies in G_source_lines when done with it */
  free(lnptr);
  fclose(stream);
}

void free_source_lines(void)
{
  for (size_t ln = 0; ln < G_source_lines_count; ++ln)
    free(G_source_lines[ln]);
}
```

I am not sure whether copying the pointers to the allocated memories by getline saved in the `lnptr` into `G_source_lines` makes it necessary to free those copies too as the function `free_source_lines` should do when done with the `G_souce_lines`, or is it enough to free `lnptr` in read_line once at the end?

Comment: Yes, you need to free verything in `free_source_lines()`.

Comment: But there's no harm in `free(lnptr)`, because `free(NULL)` doesn't do anything.

Comment: You mean I don't need to `free(lnptr)` in the else clause of the while loop? or the one outside of while?

Comment: @Barmar From the man page of getline: `If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer should be freed by the  user  program even if getline() failed.
`

Comment: Oops, missed that.

Comment: So, you could move `lnptr = NULL;` into the `if` part, and totally remove the `else` part (leaving the buffer allocated). The final `free(lnptr);` at the end of the function will then free any unused buffer.

Comment: @IanAbbott The free in the else branch frees allocated buffers if the if-test evaluates to false (`isempty() == 1`). Since a buffer is already allocated by the getline beforehands, I thought it might be cleaner to de-allocate it anyways. Is that not necessary?

Comment: The unneeded "empty"  buffer would get reused or reallocated by the next call to `getline()`, so there is no need to free until all lines have been read. There is no harm in freeing it though, as long as you never pass a "saved" or "freed" pointer value back to `getline`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's necessary to free them in `free_source_lines()`.

Since you're setting `lnptr` to `NULL` before each call to `getline()`, it's setting it to a pointer to a different buffer each time. The call to `free(lnptr)` at the end only frees the buffer that was allocated during the final, failing call, not any of the buffers that were saved in `G_source_lines`.

Comment: The `free(lnptr)` at the end is for the case that getline returns -1, thus breaking out of while loop